# Windows server 2008 R2 180 days activation in Virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, windows-activation

I have a testing machine that needs Windows server 2008 R2 running in virtualbox.
My issue is that every time I try to activate windows I get the error "*security error 0x80072F8F*"
I set the clock according to internet time
I called MS and they said WS2008 is no longer supported
I tryied also with dialup activation but it says no answer, the modem itself works and also the POTS line.
I must say that some other WS2008R2 VMs have been activated.

Right now I tried to:
• make a new VM with my existing iso
• download an iso and make a new VM
• Update Virtualbox and make a newer VM

In no case I was able to successfully validate the 180 days trial licence

How could I activate the 180 days trial licence on a Virtualbox VM?

NOTE: 
I'm not going to purchase a new licence because this machines are needed just for few months and just for testing.

EDIT:
Setting
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\OOBE for an item named MediaBootInstall` to `0` did not worked

EDIT2:
`slmgr /rearm`: this gave me other 10 days grace period, but it's still impossible to get the whole 180 days (the bottom right of the desktop does not shows "180 days left")

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The regular "trial license" is just an unactivated Windows. If you do want to activate Windows you will need a valid key.

Comment: Windows offers 180days trial licence, an unactivated ws2008 gives only 10 days before it asks for an activation (activation that could be made with a trial licence). I'm over those 10 days and I want to use the 180 days advertised by MS

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is currently not sold by Microsoft.  Why are you using that version instead of a version that is supported?  It is currently possible to activate any version of Windows you have a license to.

Comment: Because our appliance, of what the project I'm on is a little part, has been reviewed and certified to run on that, and re-certification is no-go due to time to times and costs

Answer (score 1):

The error `x80072F8F` when attempting to activate Windows is caused by the time on
your system not matching the time on the Microsoft activation server,
thus it blocks your access.

Fix the clock on the virtual machine to be correct within its declared time-zone
and it should work.

If that didn't help, check registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\OOBE`
for an item named `MediaBootInstall`. If it exists then its value
must be zero (`0`).

Another try is to run Command Prompt As Administrator and execute the command
`slmgr /rearm` and reboot.
If asked for your product key, then type it to activate Windows.

Comment: I did it -> clock, adjust time, internet time. It was my first try

Comment: I added more methods.

Comment: I've tried those but sadly none worked to get the 180 days.

Comment: Try `slmgr.vbs /upk` followed if required by `slmgr.vbs /cpky`. You can also try to set the product key via `slmgr.vbs /ipk #####-#####-#####-#####-#####`.

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 Microsoft changed the code signing method to SHA-2. It seems, that the activation is using SHA-2 as well now. After I have installed the SHA-2 update ([kb4490628](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb4490628) and [kb4474419](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb4474419)) the activation no longer errors with 0x80072F8F.

Instead it now shows "The product key you typed has been blocked from use by Microsoft".

That's understandable as 2008R2 is out of service. I suspect that there is no longer a way to get the activation for 180 days.